# Cygwin update using new setup executable: The following packages(s) had download errors

Tags: cygwin

After 3+ years, I tried to update my Cygwin packages.  There was a new setup executable, which I normally run as non-administrator.  I did this today and got the message "The following packages(s) had download errors".

It doesn't matter which site I chose.  However, the list of erroneous packages, and the length of the list. varies with the mirror.  For the same mirror, I think the list is the same.

According to Google, this is not a common problem.  [One incident](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2018-September/238632.html) I found online was solved by changing to another network.  This is not an option for me, nor is it an option to change the web proxy that my network uses.

What other solution might work?

Comment: Reinstalling Cygwin will probably work.

Comment: which mirror are you using ?

Comment: I don't recall which I used, but three or four.  So it doesn't seem mirror-specific, which is why I think it has to do with the use of web proxy.  I am not on-site and won't be for a few days.

Comment: have you tried with a new cache folder ? an empty one

Comment: As far as I know, the Cygwin setup app creates a new package folder for each mirror site.